# Implementing Phase Unwrapping Algorithm with Haskell Repa Array

Tags: algorithm, haskell, 3d, phase, repa

I'm trying to implement a Phase Unwrapping Algorithm for Three Phase Structured Light Scanning in Haskell using a Repa Array. I want to implement a flood fill based unwrapping algorithm recursing outward from the point (width / 2, height / 2). Unfortunately using that method of recursion I'm getting an out of memory exception. I'm new to Haskell and the Repa library so I was wondering whether it looks like I'm doing anything glaringly wrong. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Update (@leventov):

I am now considering implementing the following path following algorithm using mutable arrays in Yarr. (Publication: K. Chen, J. Xi, Y. Yu & J. F. Chicharo, "Fast quality-guided flood-fill phase unwrapping algorithm for threedimensional fringe pattern profilometry," in Optical Metrology and Inspection for Industrial Applications,
2010, pp. 1-9.)

[image: Path Following Algorithm]

```
 {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Odph -rtsopts  -fno-liberate-case -fllvm -optlo-O3 -XTypeOperators -XNoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

 module Scanner where

 import Data.Word
 import Data.Fixed
 import Data.Array.Repa.Eval
 import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R
 import qualified Data.Array.Repa.Repr.Unboxed as U
 import qualified Data.Array.Repa.Repr.ForeignPtr as P
 import Codec.BMP
 import Data.Array.Repa.IO.BMP
 import Control.Monad.Identity (runIdentity)
 import System.Environment( getArgs )

 type ImRead = Either Error Image
 type Avg    = P.Array R.U R.DIM2 (ImageT, ImageT, ImageT)
 type ImageT = (Word8, Word8, Word8)
 type PhaseT = (Float, Float, Float)
 type WrapT  = (Float, Int)
 type Image  = P.Array R.U R.DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)
 type Phase  = P.Array R.U R.DIM2 (Float, Float, Float)
 type Wrap   = P.Array R.U R.DIM2 (Float, Int)
 type UWrapT = (Float, Int, [(Int, Int)], String)
 type DepthT = (Float, Int, String)

 {-# INLINE noise #-}
 {-# INLINE zskew #-}
 {-# INLINE zscale #-}
 {-# INLINE compute #-}
 {-# INLINE main #-}
 {-# INLINE doMain #-}
 {-# INLINE zipImg #-}
 {-# INLINE mapWrap #-}
 {-# INLINE avgPhase #-}
 {-# INLINE doAvg #-}
 {-# INLINE doWrap #-}
 {-# INLINE doPhase #-}
 {-# INLINE isPhase #-}
 {-# INLINE diffPhase #-}
 {-# INLINE shape #-}
 {-# INLINE countM #-}
 {-# INLINE inArr #-}
 {-# INLINE idx #-}
 {-# INLINE getElem #-}
 {-# INLINE start #-}
 {-# INLINE unwrap #-}
 {-# INLINE doUnwrap #-}
 {-# INLINE doDepth #-}
 {-# INLINE write #-}

 noise :: Float
 noise = 0.1

 zskew :: Float
 zskew = 24

 zscale :: Float
 zscale = 130

 compute :: (R.Shape sh, U.Unbox e) => P.Array R.D sh e -> P.Array R.U sh e
 compute a = runIdentity (R.computeP a) 

 main :: IO ()
 main = do
      commandArguments <- getArgs
      case commandArguments of
           (file1 : file2 : file3 : _ ) -> do
                image1 <- readImageFromBMP file1
                image2 <- readImageFromBMP file2
                image3 <- readImageFromBMP file3
                doMain image1 image2 image3                                             
           _ -> putStrLn "Not enough arguments"

 doMain :: ImRead -> ImRead -> ImRead -> IO()
 doMain (Right i1) (Right i2) (Right i3) = write
      where 
           write = writeFile "out.txt" str
           (p, m, d, str) = start $ mapWrap i1 i2 i3
 doMain _ _ _ = putStrLn "Error loading image"

 zipImg :: Image -> Image -> Image -> Avg
 zipImg i1 i2 i3 = U.zip3 i1 i2 i3

 mapWrap :: Image -> Image -> Image -> Wrap
 mapWrap i1 i2 i3 = compute $ R.map wrap avg
      where
           wrap = (doWrap . avgPhase) 
           avg = zipImg i1 i2 i3

 avgPhase :: (ImageT, ImageT, ImageT) -> PhaseT
 avgPhase (i1, i2, i3) = (doAvg i1, doAvg i2, doAvg i3)

 doAvg :: ImageT -> Float
 doAvg (r, g, b) = (r1 + g1 + b1) / d1
      where
           r1 = fromIntegral r
           g1 = fromIntegral g
           b1 = fromIntegral b
           d1 = fromIntegral 765

 doWrap :: PhaseT -> WrapT
 doWrap (p1, p2, p3) = (wrap, mask)
      where 
           wrap  = isPhase $ doPhase (p1, p2, p3)
           mask  = isNoise $ diffPhase [p1, p2, p3]

 doPhase :: PhaseT -> (Float, Float)
 doPhase (p1, p2, p3) = (x1, x2)
      where
           x1 = sqrt 3 * (p1 - p3)
           x2 = 2 * p2 - p1 - p3  

 isPhase :: (Float, Float) -> Float
 isPhase (x1, x2) = atan2 x1 x2 / (2 * pi)

 diffPhase :: [Float] -> Float
 diffPhase phases = maximum phases - minimum phases

 isNoise :: Float -> Int
 isNoise phase = fromEnum $ phase <= noise

 shape :: Wrap -> [Int]
 shape wrap = R.listOfShape $ R.extent wrap

 countM :: Wrap -> (Float, Int)
 countM wrap = R.foldAllS count (0,0) wrap
      where count = (\(x, y) (i, j) -> (x, y))

 start :: Wrap -> UWrapT
 start wrap = unwrap wrap (x, y) (ph, m, [], "")
      where 
           [x0, y0] = shape wrap
           x        = quot x0 2
           y        = quot y0 2
           (ph, m)  = getElem wrap (x0, y0)

 inArr :: Wrap -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
 inArr wrap (x,y) = x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < x0 && y < y0
      where 
           [x0, y0] = shape wrap

 idx :: (Int, Int) -> (R.Z R.:. Int R.:. Int)
 idx (x, y) = (R.Z R.:. x R.:. y)

 getElem :: Wrap -> (Int, Int) -> WrapT
 getElem wrap (x, y) = wrap R.! idx (x, y)

 unwrap :: Wrap -> (Int, Int) -> UWrapT -> UWrapT
 unwrap wrap (x, y) (ph, m, done, str) =
      if
           not $ inArr wrap (x, y) || 
           (x, y) `elem` done ||
           toEnum m::Bool
      then
           (ph, m, done, str) 
      else
           up
           where
                unwrap' = doUnwrap wrap (x, y) (ph, m, done, str)
                right   = unwrap wrap (x+1, y) unwrap'
                left    = unwrap wrap (x-1, y) right
                down    = unwrap wrap (x, y+1) left
                up      = unwrap wrap (x, y-1) down

 doUnwrap :: Wrap -> (Int, Int) -> UWrapT -> UWrapT
 doUnwrap wrap (x, y) (ph, m, done, str) = unwrapped
      where
           unwrapped = (nph, m, (x, y):done, out)
           (phase, mask) = getElem wrap (x, y)
           rph   = fromIntegral $ round ph
           off   = phase - (ph - rph)
           nph   = ph + (mod' (off + 0.5) 1) - 0.5
           out   = doDepth wrap (x, y) (nph, m, str)

 doDepth :: Wrap -> (Int, Int) -> DepthT -> String
 doDepth wrap (x, y) (ph, m, str) = write (x, ys, d, str)
      where
           [x0, y0] = shape wrap
           ys       = y0 - y
           ydiff    = fromIntegral (y - (quot y0 2))
           plane    = 0.5 - ydiff / zskew
           d        = (ph - plane) * zscale


 write :: (Int, Int, Float, String) -> String
 write (x, y, depth, str) = str ++ vertex
      where
           vertex = xstr ++ ystr ++ zstr
           xstr   = show x ++ " "
           ystr   = show y ++ " "
           zstr   = show depth ++ "\n"
```

Comment: Could you please add imports and whatever else this needs to compile with a `ghc --make`?

Comment: @jberryman Added complete module to allow for compiling. The first (wrapping) part of the algorithm works as expected. Command line args are three bmp images (with shifted phase patterns).

Comment: @leventov Thanks for your advice. I had previously tried inlining all the 'worker' functions with no change to the out of memory exception and unfortunately adding INLINE to all functions didn't work either. I've looked at your Yarr library for Haskell and am interested in using the mutable array structures to implement the algorithm in the picture above (or the existing flood fill algorithm). Could you maybe outline how I would start going about using these array structures please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for wasting some your time by my first misleading advice.

You should use another 2-dimensional array of pixel states (already visited or not) instead of

```
(x, y) `elem` done
```

because the latter takes linear time.

Examples of solving almost the same task: for [`repa` and `vector`](https://github.com/leventov/yarr/blob/466ffc298e73b378d3800e9e5bc6e42b403a3a1c/tests/canny-repa.hs#L303), and for [`yarr`](https://github.com/leventov/yarr/blob/466ffc298e73b378d3800e9e5bc6e42b403a3a1c/tests/canny.hs#L222).

Perhaps, you have out of memory exception because of building a string by appending to the end (in `write` function) - the worst solution, linear time and memory consumption. You would better aggregate results using cons (`:`) and write it to the output file at the end, in reverse order. Even better - write results to another unboxed `Vector` of `(Int, Int, Float)` elements (allocate vector of `width*height` size - as upper bound of possible size).